# How can I merge 3 lists in Python, so that the first part of the new list is the 3 first parts from the original lists

Tags: python

For example, if I have 3 lists such as:

```
[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]
```

How can I merge them into:

```
[159,2610,3711,4812]
```

Comment: `[int(''.join(x)) for x in zip(*(map(str, i) for i in data))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` the lists elementwise, convert each `int` to `str`, `join` them, then convert back to `int` within a list comprehension.

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]
>>> [int(''.join(str(i) for i in j)) for j in zip(*l)]
[159, 2610, 3711, 4812]
```

Edit:
If you already have a list of strings

```
>>> [''.join(i) for i in zip(*l)]
```

Comment: They're not actually numbers, that was just an example, should really have used:       >>> [a,b,c,d], [e,f,g,h], [i,j,k,l]

Comment: @Nick in that case it's the same idea but a little simpler, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> lists = [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]

>>> [int(''.join(map(str, x)) for x in zip(*lists)]
[159, 2610, 3711, 4812]

>>> [int('%d' * len(x) % x) for x in zip(*lists)]
[159, 2610, 3711, 4812]

>>> map(int, map(('{}' * len(lists)).format, *lists))
[159, 2610, 3711, 4812]
```

(Last one is Python 2, Python 3 needs a `list(...)` around it.)

Answer (score 0):

```
x,y,z = [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]
result = []
for i in xrange(len(x)):
    result.append(''.join(map(str, [x[i],y[i],z[i]]))

In [233]: result
Out[233]: ['159', '2610', '3711', '4812']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a more compact method.

I think it's more readable and easy to understand. You can refer as below:

This is your var I delcare response:

```
data = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]
```

Let's invoke `map` and `zip` functions.

```
new_data = zip(*(map(str, i) for i in data))
```

Check the data is renewed to distribute.

```
print new_data
# [('1', '5', '9'), ('2', '6', '10'), ('3', '7', '11'), ('4', '8', '12')]
```

You can print new_list when finishing calculating result:

```
print [int(''.join(x)) for x in new_data]
# [159, 2610, 3711, 4812]
```